# qApp versus QApplication.instance()

Tags: python, pyqt, instance, pyqt5, qapplication

With PyQt5, both of these return the application object:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
app = QtWidgets.qApp
for i in app.arguments()[1:]:
    ...
```

But why does `print(QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() is QtWidgets.qApp)` print `False`?

Answer (score 36):

The difference between `QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()` and `QtWidgets.qApp` is that the latter is a *static module variable* that must be created when the module is first imported. This results in the following initially baffling behaviour:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>> inst = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
>>> qapp = QtWidgets.qApp
>>> (inst, qapp)
(None, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication object at 0x7ff3c8bd3948>)
```

So even though no `QApplication` object has been created yet, the `qApp` variable still points to a `QApplication` instance. If modules were more like classes, so that they could have dynamic properties, it would be possible for `qApp` to work exactly like `QApplication.instance()` does and initially return `None`. But because it is static, it must always return an object of the correct type, so that it can later refer to the same underlying C++ object as `QApplication.instance()`.

However, it's important to note that `qApp` is initially just an *empty* wrapper:

```
>>> qapp.objectName()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QApplication has been deleted
```

Once the `QApplication` is created, though, they will both point to the same thing:

```
>>> app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
>>> app.setObjectName('foo')
>>> qapp.objectName()
'foo'
```

So the reason why `(QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() is QtWidgets.qApp)` returns `False`, is that the two objects are different python wrappers around the same underlying C++ object.

It's important to be aware of this point if you ever need to create your own sublass of `QApplication`, but still want to use `qApp`:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>> class MyApp(QtWidgets.QApplication):
...     def hello(self): print('Hello World')
...
>>> myapp = MyApp([])
>>> myapp.hello()
Hello World
>>>
>>> QtWidgets.qApp
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication object at 0x7f5e42f40948>
>>> QtWidgets.qApp.hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QApplication' object has no attribute 'hello'
>>>
>>> inst = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
>>> inst
<__main__.MyApp object at 0x7f5e42f409d8>
>>> inst.hello()
Hello World
```

The only way around this is to explicitly overwrite the `qApp` module variable (and obviously ensure that this is done before it can be imported by other modules):

```
>>> QtWidgets.qApp = myapp
>>> QtWidgets.qApp.hello()
Hello World
```